# How to properely pass this pointer to AJAX helper function in JQ?

Tags: jquery

I have some links, which on click sends some data to the server. The answer comes in 3-5 seconds, so for that time i need to block currently clicked link that until i get a response it wouldn't be possible to click it.

My code looks like:

```
jQuery('#some-div').find('.some-links').click(function(){
    jQuery.post(
        ajax_url,
        values,
        function(response) {
            // Here i need to use element, which i clicked above
        },
        'JSON'
    );
});
```

Comment: Stating a question in comment is not a good idea. Please be more specific about that. Can you correct the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use $.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context to the callback method

```
jQuery('#some-div').find('.some-links').click(function(){
    jQuery.post(
        ajax_url,
        values,
        $.proxy(function(response) {
            // `this` points to the element
            // Here i need to use element, which i clicked above
        }, this),
        'JSON'
    );
});
```

Use a closure variable

```
jQuery('#some-div').find('.some-links').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery.post(
        ajax_url,
        values,
        $.proxy(function(response) {
            // `$this` points to the element
            // Here i need to use element, which i clicked above
        }, this),
        'JSON'
    );
});
```

Comment: Is it answer for the question?

Comment: @360flowMichael currently testig

Comment: @360flowMichael sorry I went with `// Here i need to use element, which i clicked above` didn't read the question

Comment: @ArunPJohny no, you are right. Question is in how to pass this. Other text was only for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You could set some variable unique for each link you click like that:

```
jQuery('#some-div').find('.some-links').click(function(){
    if($(this).data('post-pending')){
        return;
    }
    $(this).data('post-pending', true);

    var that = this;
    jQuery.post(
        ajax_url,
        values,
        function(response) {
            // Here i need to use element, which i clicked above
            $(that).data('post-pending', false);
        },
        'JSON'
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the `.data()` function to store a little flag that tells you whether the element is currently in use or free to use.

```
jQuery('#some-div').find('.some-links').click(function(){
    var state = $(this).data('blocked');
    if (!blocked) {
        $(this).data('blocked',true);
        jQuery.post(
            ajax_url,
            values,
            function(response) {
                // Here i need to use element, which i clicked above
                $(this).data('blocked',false);
            },
            'JSON'
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: If you implement this pattern, make sure you handle an ajax error occurring also otherwise your blocked flag will never get reset.